# How to override a function written in MDdialogue

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

I'm using material mddialog. I have a function written as below

```
sendSMS() {
  console.log('CLICKEDDDDD');
}
```

How can I overrride that function with some custom function which i want to write in my component that using the mddialog?

I have tried to do this

```
dialogRef.componentInstance.sendSMS() = function() {
  //blh blah
};
```

But I'm getting error as

> the left side of an assignment expression must be a variable or a property class`

How to fix that? I am getting zero idea until now. 
I have been wasted my 1 day for this. I hope someone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how can I that function as abstract function? as a variable in the mddialogue and oveeride that varible in my componnet?

Comment: the error message states that the left side should be an variable, so maybe just remove the `()`.